# "Deployment target" and "Architectures" for ios development

Tags: ios, xcode

From the Apple Xcode Build Setting reference, we can see that :

> **iOS Deployment Target** identifies the earliest iOS version the product is to run on
>
> **Architectures** specifies the architectures (ABIs, processor models) to which the binary is targeted

What's the relationship between these two concepts? When I set build settings, they should be consistent?

For example, I want to target iOS 5. I think I need to find out all the devices which can run iOS 5 or later versions iOS, and collect all CPU architectures from these devices. Suppose there are three kinds of architectures from these devices: A,B,C. I should set the architecture to "A,B,C"? Or, if the oldest architecture is A, then I can assume backwards compatibility, set the architecture only to "A"?

Please correct me If my understanding is wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old but.

The `iOS Deployment Target` does exactly as the docs say.

The `Architectures` is basically a list of all the CPU architectures for which Xcode will compile your source.

If you have iOS 5 as your `iOS Deployment Target` and try to build & run your app on a device with iOS 6 but your `Architectures` list does not contain the CPU architecture of that device, you will get an error because your app hasn't been compiled to run on that CPU.

Hope that helps